# A good place to start with angularjs ui (bootstrap) and ng-animate to create a wizard similar to boostrap-application wizard

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, wizard, ng-animate

I am pretty new to AngularJS and would like to create a wizard, similar to the one found here (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famoffat%2Fbootstrap-application-wizard&ei=ZSomUtrZN_ShsQTy3ICIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGGfJ85a77baLTojgaOHUK0miVHHg&bvm=bv.51495398,d.dmg) using AngularJS UI and ng-animate.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Melroy

Comment: For animations, you can use this site: [Ng-Animate](http://www.nganimate.org)